# How to periodically watch a file from a list of files

Tags: files, tail, watch

I've a running java project that prints it's output to a file named in according to the current time:
`03:45 ==> 03.out`
`13:24 ==> 13.out`
`etc...`
Now I want to watch tail of the file currently having the project's output. Please note that I know the current file name in a specific meta file.
If I execute the following:
`watch $(tail specific_meta_file)`
It's not working since it watch only the file at the current time not in another time

Comment: You want to watch the file at a time in the future?

Answer (score 3):

Tail can watch multiple files at once:

```
$ tail -f file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 ...
```

Comment: I 'm searching a more suitable solution. I want to watch just the current file (the file is being written by the project currently) not all the files at the same time!

Comment: @MohsenAbasi I understood file are writen one at a time, so once output to 03.out is exhausted, you would see only "active" file.

Comment: @Archemar I don't want see the active file. I just want to tail the active file: sometimes 01.out, sometimes 02.out, etc. If I tail all the files together in according to your answer, the outputs will be mixed. I just want to see the output from 1 file (active file) not all the files together!!!!